# MySQL Query in AJAX to PHP Call Defeated By PHP's "strip_tags" Function

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Behind the scenes in my PHP application, I have an AJAX call that sends a URL encoded string (via JavaScript's "encodeURIComponent" function) to a PHP function for use in an MySQL query: For example, the query looks like so:

```
select ID,Type from table where Type like '' and ID = n;
```

And the "Type" string passed into the PHP function looks like so:

```
"size < 5"
```

Which gives a MySQL query that looks like so:

```
select ID,Type from table where Type like 'size < 5' and ID = n;
```

The only issue is that when the PHP function gets the string, it immediately uses its "strip_tags" function to clean the string, which turns my end query into:

```
select ID,Type from table where Type like 'size ' and ID = n;
```

I don't want to **not** use "strip_tags" because of SQL injection concerns, but the very thing I am using to protect myself is keeping me from performing a required function. Is there any safe way around this issue?

Comment: How are you cleaning your input? Please show the code you are using to build your query.

Comment: strip_tags does nothing to prevent sql injection. It destroys data, that's what matters. You should use prepared statements to avoid sql injection. Have a look at [The Great Escapism](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: Did you use any strip_tags function from your own?

Comment: @Jasper I am cleaning it at the "GET". I'm using strip_tags($_GET['Type']).

Comment: @JensonMJohn No, I am purely using PHP's strip_tags function.

Comment: @VMai I never thought about using a prepared statement for a "select". Isn't that a bit of an overkill, or that the standard way of doing things?

Comment: You want to look into cleaning your input, there are obviously things there for you to learn (don't worry, it's not too tricky). Clean/sanitize everything before/while concocting a query, it will only help.

Comment: That's good practice. It can't be standard judging by the database related questions. It should be standard, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Use PDO, try something like this.

```
       <?php

        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=yourHostName;dbname=yourDatabaseName', "Username", "Password");

        $query = "SELECT `ID`,`Type` FROM table WHERE `Type` LIKE :type";

        $prepare = $pdo->prepare($query, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));

        $type = "size < 5";

        $prepare->execute(array(':type' => $type));

        $array_result = $prepare->fetchAll();
        ?>
```